# How often were slaves raised by their parents in 19th century USA?

Tags: united-states, slavery

American slave owners wanted their slaves to have children, but they didn't always allow their slaves to marry, and often sold families piecemeal. About what percentage of slaves were raised by both biological parents until adulthood?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ira Berlin says that about one third of the enslaved population lived in two-parent families. (I was not able to find figures specifically concerning children.)

> While family separation was a pervasive aspect of slavery, it would be a mistake to assume that all families were destroyed. There are many instances of enslaved spouses and children living together on the same plantation, sometimes even in the same cabin. Some slaveholders encouraged such arrangements, believing that a stable family life would make their slaves more contented and productive. The pattern of slaveholding in the Chesapeake in the early years of the nineteenth century probably reflected the general situation throughout the slaveholding South. In this region, **approximately one-third of the enslaved population lived in two-parent families**.

(Ira Berlin, *Many Thousands Gone: The First Two Centuries of Slavery in North America*)

This roughly corresponds to the way another researcher describes the life of adult women:

> Most slave women lived in nuclear or extended families on the same plantation, and if their families were disrupted, they worked hard to establish new ones. In the late eighteenth century, **only about 20 percent of all African American women lived in nuclear families with a husband and children. About 50 percent lived in extended families or had close ties with siblings and other kin.** The remaining 30 percent lived alone, most often as a result of death or forced migration. But even those women who did not live in nuclear families forged important and lasting bonds with kin and other slaves, forming a network of people who provided emotional and social support.

(Deborah Gray White, *Ar'n't I a Woman?: Female Slaves in the Plantation South.*)

Comment: Note that there is difference between the quote's claim "one-third of the enslaved population" (which seems to include adults) and your phrase "one third of slave children"...

Comment: You are right! I have edited the answer to reflect that.